# Android Studio doesn't recognize JDK

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My Android Studio suddenly stopped recognizing JDK. it starts fine with no error messages.
I have JDK 1,7 (x86 version) on windows 8.1. Environment variable is defined in the system variables and I can run java -version command from cmd with no issue.
 following screen shot describe the problem clearly:
[image]

Comment: Go to File -> Project Structure ,  select SDK Location. Does it show correct path of Android SDK & JDK. Do choose again JDK and see if it works.

Comment: Try File | Invalidate Caches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending one night trying to solve this problem, i just did as suggested by [yole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147024/yole)

So Simple :
 File ----> Invalidate.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check if both JDK and SDK are set correctly.

In the **current project**:

- Go to File > Project Structure..
- Explore the sections "*Android SDK
  Location*" and "*JDK Location*" (Put the complete paths)
- Click OK to save changes

For **projects default**:

- Close current Project (File > Close project)
- Click on Configure > Project Defaults > Project Structure
- Explore the sections "*Android SDK
  Location*" and "*JDK Location*" (Put the complete paths)
- Click OK to save changes

Restart Android Studio and try again.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnpvC.png
(I cannot post images directly)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading to build tool 22.0.1.
I solved this issue by removing dependencies and adding it again like app-compact and play services.